# How to get and update single/multiple Custom Fields in post.php page?

Tags: wordpress

I made simple form where I can add and update Custom fields in WordPress `post.php` page.

**The working code I used**

I added this code in the end of my themes **function.php** :

```
define('MY_WORDPRESS_FOLDER',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('MY_THEME_FOLDER',str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__)));
define('MY_THEME_PATH','/' . substr(MY_THEME_FOLDER,stripos(MY_THEME_FOLDER,'wp-content')));

add_action('admin_init','my_meta_init');

function my_meta_init()
{
    // review the function reference for parameter details
    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script
    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

    //wp_enqueue_script('my_meta_js', MY_THEME_PATH . '/custom/meta.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_style('my_meta_css', MY_THEME_PATH . '/custom/meta.css');

    // review the function reference for parameter details
    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

    foreach (array('post','page') as $type) 
    {
        add_meta_box('my_all_meta', 'My Custom Meta Box', 'my_meta_setup', $type, 'normal', 'high');
    }

    add_action('save_post','my_meta_save');
}

function my_meta_setup()
{
    global $post;

    // using an underscore, prevents the meta variable
    // from showing up in the custom fields section
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);

    // instead of writing HTML here, lets do an include
    include(MY_THEME_FOLDER . '/custom/meta.php');

    // create a custom nonce for submit verification later
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="my_meta_noncename" value="' . wp_create_nonce(__FILE__) . '" />';
}

function my_meta_save($post_id) 
{
    // authentication checks

    // make sure data came from our meta box
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['my_meta_noncename'],__FILE__)) return $post_id;

    // check user permissions
    if ($_POST['post_type'] == 'page') 
    {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) return $post_id;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) return $post_id;
    }

    // authentication passed, save data

    // var types
    // single: _my_meta[var]
    // array: _my_meta[var][]
    // grouped array: _my_meta[var_group][0][var_1], _my_meta[var_group][0][var_2]

    $current_data = get_post_meta($post_id, '_my_meta', TRUE);  

    $new_data = $_POST['_my_meta'];

    my_meta_clean($new_data);

    if ($current_data) 
    {
        if (is_null($new_data)) delete_post_meta($post_id,'_my_meta');
        else update_post_meta($post_id,'_my_meta',$new_data);
    }
    elseif (!is_null($new_data))
    {
        add_post_meta($post_id,'_my_meta',$new_data,TRUE);
    }

    return $post_id;
}

function my_meta_clean(&$arr)
{
    if (is_array($arr))
    {
        foreach ($arr as $i => $v)
        {
            if (is_array($arr[$i])) 
            {
                my_meta_clean($arr[$i]);

                if (!count($arr[$i])) 
                {
                    unset($arr[$i]);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                if (trim($arr[$i]) == '') 
                {
                    unset($arr[$i]);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!count($arr)) 
        {
            $arr = NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created a folder named "**custom**" inside my themes folder and saved this 2 files in there:  meta.php and meta.css

**meta.php** looks like:

```
<div class="my_meta_control">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras orci lorem, bibendum in pharetra ac, luctus ut mauris. Phasellus dapibus elit et justo malesuada eget <code>functions.php</code>.</p>

    <label>Name</label>

    <p>
        <input type="text" name="_my_meta[link]" value="<?php if(!empty($meta['link'])) echo $meta['link']; ?>"/>
        <span>Enter in a name</span>
    </p>

    <label>Description <span>(optional)</span></label>

    <p>
        <textarea name="_my_meta[description]" rows="3"><?php if(!empty($meta['description'])) echo $meta['description']; ?></textarea>
        <span>Enter in a description</span>
    </p>

</div>
```

**meta.css** looks like :

```
.my_meta_control .description { display:none; }

.my_meta_control label { display:block; font-weight:bold; margin:6px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:12px; }

.my_meta_control label span { display:inline; font-weight:normal; }

.my_meta_control span { color:#999; display:block; }

.my_meta_control textarea, .my_meta_control input[type='text'] { margin-bottom:3px; width:99%; }

.my_meta_control h4 { color:#999; font-size:1em; margin:15px 6px; text-transform:uppercase; }
```

With this code above I get this result:

[image]

Now I can add and update Name and Description Custom Fields here which works **great**.

**Thats what I wanted BUT the problem IS:**

This box will use "Name" and "Description" from: `_my_meta` and I don't want it.
Previously I have already saved Custom Fields Values to all my published posts as: `phone`, `home_city`, `home_country`, `name` ++

**My question is:**
How can I modify this Code to work with my already saved custom fields instead of using this new `_my_meta` ? As mentioned my custom field names is: `phone`, `home_city`, `home_country`, `name` ++

Answer (score 1):

Simple, you don't need `_my_meta`. And before anything is worth noting that your example uses this single meta key to store multiple values as a [serialized array](http://nacin.com/2010/04/18/wordpress-serializing-data/), `_my_meta[link]` and `_my_meta[description]`. So it looks like this after deserializing:

```
'my_meta' = array(
   'link' => 'some value',
   'description' => 'another value'
)
```

The thing is, it's practical to use a single custom field as a container for many key/values, but this is not good if you plan to use those fields for searching results or ordering a query by meta key. In this case it's better to use single fields.

As you say that you already have custom fields, much probably they are single fields, in which case you'd do the following to adapt the code.

In `my_meta_setup()`:

```
$phone = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'phone', TRUE );
$phone = !empty($phone) ? $phone : ''; // this makes the HTML cleaner
$home_city = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'home_city', TRUE );
$home_city = !empty($home_city) ? $home_city : '';
?>
<input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="home_city" value="<?php echo $home_city; ?>"/>
```

In `my_meta_save()`:

```
$phone = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'phone', TRUE );  
$home_city = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'home_city', TRUE );  
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'phone', $new_phone );
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'home_city', $new_home_city );
```

---

Other notes:

- put `wp_enqueue_style` inside a [**`wp_enqueue_scripts`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action hook.
- avoid using `constants`. We can get the theme folder with [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) and the path with [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory).
- WordPress path is already defined in `ABSPATH` and the URL we can get with `site_url()`, but you probably don't need this.
- the action hook `save_post` takes 2 arguments, the second being `$post`, we don't need the global

  ```
  add_action( 'save_post','my_meta_save', 10, 2 );
  function my_meta_save( $post_id, $post ) {}
  ```

Comment: @b: I updated my_meta_setup and my_meta_save codes with your Codes. Unfortunately I could not see any values. I had a value in $phone but some how now its empty after using this code. So I guess it works but I don't understand what to delete from my old code? Could you please rewrite my code? Thanks a Million.

Comment: If I rewrite your code, you won't learn how to do it by yourself ;) Using a test installation you can `var_dump($variable); die();` to go inspecting your code until you find the glitch. Go comparing with the values in the default meta box "Custom Fields". Many working examples in [this search query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Badd_meta_boxes+%2Bsave_post+%2B+wp_verify_nonce+is%3Aa).

Comment: @b: You are right :) Now I learned the `global $post;` is important in `my_meta_setup()` so now I can sell ALL the values. But updating is still a problem. Do I need `global $post;` and `return $post_id;` in `my_meta_save()`? When I update now the values just gets empty.

Comment: Cool ;) I've added an extra note to the Answer regarding `$post`. And no, we don't need to return nothing in an `action` hook, we simply use `return;` to break further execution of the function.

Comment: `var_dump($new_phone); die();` results: `NULL`

Comment: @b: I have removed all off `my_meta_clean`. Now I successfully got results from `var_dump($new_phone) die();` as expected but they still don save in Custom Field. And if I add a line like `$new_phone = "98765432";` in `my_meta_save` then its saved correctly. Thats confusing cause `$new_phone` have a value in both cases but don't save when I add value into field.

Comment: You may probably want to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). I've already outlined here the steps to adapt your code correctly, if you're not being able to process the data, we should be able to isolate the issue in a clean Q&A, this one is becoming confusing.